# Intellij any way to turn off overwrite confirmation?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

Given the power of intellij, one would think disabling the overwrite file confirmation popup is possible. It appears after right-clicking a file in the Project Tool window, clicking copy, and clicking paste anywhere a file with the exact same name exists:
[image: overwrite?]

I could find no specific setting to do it. Ideas? (pun intended)

Comment: Overwrite of what? Please share more details.

Comment: What are the exact steps to get this popup?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Apologies - late night trying to meet a deadline and not enough coffee this morning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a potentially dangerous operation, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't provide an option to skip this dialog. When overwriting multiple files, there will be an option to do it for all files at once.

Comment: I disagree that the label "potentially dangerous operation" applies here when three levels of redundancy (Local History, local VCS, remote VCS) can undo a 'mistake' in seconds. Philosophically speaking, when software is designed for **signficant** individualization, it should not (somewhat) arbitrarily constrain behavior.

Comment: You can always use your favorite file manager for such operations which hopefully has an option to skip such confirmations.